# python solution for feed provider

Tags: python, feed

I want to build a site same as : http://www.feedmyinbox.com/ , 
and post all my google reader subscriptions(100+) to my gmail, (in separate mails)

so I need create a feed fetcher server, get all the feeds, post new ones to my gmail.

are there any python based feed fetcher library? I know there is some feed parser, I think there is a all-in-one solution somewhere..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got a great tool to do this:

http://www.allthingsrss.com/rss2email/

maybe I can port it on gae..(oh, email quota cost more then I can afford..)

Answer (score 1):

I had  a similar question about a year ago.

Honestly, Most things like this are built off of the Universal Feed Parser (some feed parser).

Using the feed parser is a huge step in the direction you are moving.

The world of Python is full of modules you could use, Beautiful Soup, etc, but honestly, the UFP is what you want.

Take a look at this toot:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipufp.html

You would want to put your mail code in the part in this forloop:

```
 for label, prop, trunc in COMMON_ITEM_PROPERTIES:
            value = item[prop]
            if trunc:
                value = value[:trunc] + u'...'
            print >> output, INDENT, label, value
        print >> output, INDENT, u'---
```